# Convert object to datetime to show '%m/%d/%Y'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a CSV file which has dates in the below format, when I open it in Excel I can see that it has the year 2020 also. I am trying to show the year when I load the CSV in Pandas but am getting an error.

On some other threads I saw that I need to add `errors='coerce'`  to my `pd.to_datetime` code but that leads to 02/29 being overwritten by blank, and also I have to remove the %Y from my code in order for this to work.

Date
18-Feb
19-Feb
20-Feb
21-Feb
22-Feb
23-Feb
24-Feb
25-Feb
26-Feb
27-Feb
28-Feb
29-Feb
1-Mar
2-Mar
3-Mar

```
In [524]:OpenTable_US_states_trans['Date'].dtype
Out[524]: dtype('O')

In [525]: OpenTable_US_states_trans['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(OpenTable_US_states_trans.Date, format='%m/%d/%Y')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    431             try:
--> 432                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    433                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-548-2f5d18782e5d> in <module>
----> 1 OpenTable_US_states_trans['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(OpenTable_US_states_trans.Date, format='%m/%d') #, errors='coerce'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    726             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    727         else:
--> 728             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    729             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    730     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    433                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
    434             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 435                 raise e
    436 
    437     if result is None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    397             if result is None:
    398                 try:
--> 399                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
    400                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    401                     )

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Comment: You'll have to specify a year to avoid trouble with leap years, something like `pd.to_datetime('2020 ' + df['Date'], format='%Y %d-%b')`

Comment: Thanks! that worked